# Character array overflow eventhough size is specified while defining

Tags: arrays, c, string

My code for printing file names like "000.jpg" works find till num is 32, after that is starts displaying file name as "033.jpg!" or some other symbols at the end of the file name.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void filename (int a, char str[]);

int main (void)
{

    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    char str[7] = "000.jpg";

    filename (num, str);

    printf("File name is %s\n", str);
}

void filename (int a, char str[])
{
    if (0 <= a && a <= 9)
    {
        str[2] = a + 48;
    }
    else
    {
        str[2] = (a % 10) + 48;
        float b = (float) a/10;
        str[1] =  ((int) b % 10) + '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your filename pattern has seven characters. The character buffer `str` also has seven characters. In C, a string is terminated with an additional null character, `'\0'`. All system functions like `fopen` or `puts` expect null-terminated strings. You need eight characters in `str`. Better yet, let the compiler figure out how much you need: `char str[] = "###.jpg";`.

Comment: In addition to @MOehm comment, `sprintf(str, "%.3d.jpg", num);` is shorter and less error-prone.